# QuickOSM plugin crashes when using layer extents for query

Tags: qgis, quickosm

I'm trying to use QuickOSM to find some items within the extents of a polygon layer, but every time I run a query with the "extent of a layer" radio box checked, QGIS immediately closes. This happened with every layer I tried, in several different coordinate systems. (Using the map canvas extents worked the way I expected it to.)

I did a little searching, but the closest I came to my problem was [this bug report](https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/37), which was resolved in 2014.

Is there still a problem with layer extents in QuickOSM, or if not, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Am I using older, or incompatible, versions of QGIS or QuickOSM?

(The versions I'm using are QGIS 2.18.0 on Linux Mint 17.3, and QuickOSM plugin version is 1.4.5.)

Comment: Same crash here. It seems that `extent of a layer` is not implemented as expected. You should re-report the issue on Github.

Comment: I opened a new issue on their GitHub site, we'll see what they say.

Comment: A strange development: I was having trouble using `pyuic4` (different project), and eventually commented out the lines for `sip.setapi()` in QTCore.py. After doing that the QuickOSM plugin would run the query with extents from a layer, but "generate query" still crashes.

Comment: I just tested with QGIS 2.18.1 on Windows and Linux Mint, and it works as expected.

Comment: I upgraded to 2.18.1 recently as well @AndreJ, maybe that (rather than messing with setapi) was what made the difference for me as well.

Comment: Just tested again: run query works, but show query, then run crashes. I think you should update the bugreport https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/88

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in QuickOSM. Thanks for the bug report https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/88
This has been fixed in the plugin. You should update your plugin in QGIS.

Comment: Just upgraded and tried it -- everything works as expected. Thanks!